# Summary of new features in WCF 2.0?

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, xmpp

Is there a good reference, or summary list, of new features in WCF 2.0/VS2010?

I'm trying to do a justification proposal for a project, to migrate from Jabber to WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.aspnetpro.com/articles/2009/04/asp200904mb_f/asp200904mb_f.asp

Answer (score 3):

Not answering your question in particular, but WCF 2.0's not going to come out for quite some time, so I'd base my evaluation against the current WCF version.